# How to create wifi hotspot from ethernet network?

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, hot-spot, wireless-access-point

My computer connected to internet via cable (Ethernet). I want to share this internet to my android phone. How to create hotspot from my computer? I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Go to Network Icon on top panel -> Edit Connections

2.Click the Add button in the pop-up window.

3.Choose Wi-Fi from the drop-down menu when you’re asked to choose a connection type.

4.In next window, do:
Type in a connection name. The name will be used later.
Type in a SSID
Select mode: Infrastructure
Device MAC address: select your wireless card from drop-down menu.

5.Go to Wi-Fi Security tab, select security type WPA & WPA2 Personal and set a password.

6.Go to IPv4 Settings tab, from Method drop-down box select Shared to other computers.

When done, click the save button.

After above steps, a configuration file created under /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections directory. File name is same to the connection name you typed in step 4.

Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> on keyboard to open terminal. When it opens, paste the commands below and hit enter to edit the configuration file:

`gksu gedit /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/wifi-hotspot`

Replace wifi-hotspt with the connection name you typed in step 4.

When the file opens, find out the line `mode=infrastructure` and change it to `mode=ap`. Finally save the file.

When everything’s done, enable WIFI from Network Manager icon on the panel. It should automatically connect to the hotspot you created. If not, select “Connect to Hidden Wi-Fi Network ...” and select it from the drop-down box.

Now you can search and connect the access point from your Android mobile...

Comment: Is there anyway I can hidden this AP? I mean, make it invisible.

Comment: Did you mean to invisible your access point to others, so others will not able to see your wifi connection ?

Comment: Yes, how to make the connection invisible?